# Getting sonarlint error in eclipse while trying to get value from hashmap

Tags: java, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm getting error like **"Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value"**, while trying to get value from hashmap.

**Code:**

```
String promolevelname = eventCampiagnResponseObj.getEventCampMap().get(Integer.valueOf(sceobj[18].toString())).keySet().stream().findFirst().get();
```

Please give me a solution to resolve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suggests that the code line

```
eventCampiagnResponseObj.getEventCampMap().get(Integer.valueOf(sceobj[18].toString())).keySet().stream().findFirst()
```

is returning an Optional object, which you should check if it's not 'null' and only then execute get() on it.

One possible solution would be this:

```
Optional<String> promolevelnameOpt = eventCampiagnResponseObj.getEventCampMap().get(Integer.valueOf(sceobj[18].toString())).keySet().stream().findFirst().get();
if (promolevelnameOpt.isPresent()) {
  promolevelname = promolevelnameOpt.get();
} else {
  // promolevelnameOpt contains null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`findFirst` returns `Optional` but it will throw `NoSuchElementException` if there is no value. So you need to check if there is a value present.

```
Optional<String> value = obj.getOptional()
if (value.isPresent()) {
    value.get();
}
```

In your situation it should look like this:

```
Optional<String> optionalValue = eventCampiagnResponseObj.getEventCampMap().get(Integer.valueOf(sceobj[18].toString())).keySet().stream().findFirst();
if (optionalValue .isPresent()) {
    String promolevelname  = optionalValue.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.get()` you could use [`.orElse(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-)

So your code becomes :

```
String promolevelname = eventCampiagnResponseObj.getEventCampMap().get(Integer.valueOf(sceobj[18].toString())).keySet().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
```